monitoring user windows server on zabbix
Since the Windows Template zabbix does not show any data about current users who are logged onto a Windows Server, is there any way to enable this?
I need to view the currently logged on users, as well as the history of previous user logons.
I mean, should I find any way using scripts or anything?
I really appreciate you guys
